# R copy svg device to png

Tags: r, svg, export, png

I start a SVG device with recording on:

```
svg(...)
dev.control("enable")
```

Then do my plot:

```
...
```

I'd like to, also, export it as a PNG file. For that, I need to copy the current device to a new device (for that, recording must be on):

```
dev.copy(png, ...)
```

Now I close both devices (the PNG and the SVG):

```
dev.off()
dev.off()
```

The PNG file is a valid image but it is blank, and the SVG is created correctly with all elements.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Doing the opposite way, that is, starting with `png(...)` device and then `dev.copy(svg, ...)` works...